# Обособляется ли слово «после»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, наречия

<...> девочка бормотала под нос и ***после*** оглянулась, посмотреть на дверь.

Где нужно поставить запятые? Было бы хорошо, чтобы немного разъяснили.

Comment: Желательно давать фразу полностью, присовокупив своё видение проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые не нужны: "...девочка бормотала под нос и после оглянулась посмотреть на дверь". Или можно написать "оглянулась, чтобы посмотреть на дверь".

Но вообще предложение построено некорректно: во-первых, не хватает дополнения при глаголе "бормотала" (что бормотала?), во-вторых, глаголы должны быть одного вида: "девочка пробормотала что-то под нос и оглянулась *(слово "посмотреть" можно смело опустить)* на дверь".